# Как вывести картинку, зная её путь хранения в Галерее

Tags: android

Пытаюсь вывести изображение из Галереи по его пути, сохраненному в SQLite.

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
      yourImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);//это работает

    File realPath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
    photoPath = String.valueOf(realPath); //путь вноситься в базу, работает

....
 photoPath = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imgAddress"));
 yourImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("file://" + photoPath));
 //А вот это уже не работает.
....
```

String photoPath выводит красиво (проверил). НО.. само фото никак не выводится. Пробовал без "file://" - ничего. Подскажите правильный путь.

Comment: А разрешение на доступ к ФС Вы получили? Когда Вы используете `uri`, то картинку Вам передаёт галерея, а когда Вы напрямую обращаетесь к файлу - Ваше приложение должно иметь к нему доступ. Да и почему Вы решили хранить в базе реальный путь, а не использовать тот же `uri` из галереи и тот же `Image.setImageURI`

Comment: Я всю жизнь работал с PHP/MySQL. Это классика - хранить в базе пути к изображениям. Изображение владельца  должно по клику загрузиться из Галереи ( что делается легко), а потом загружаться каждый раз при входе в приложение автоматически. Может я чего-то не улавливаю. Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: В Андроиде обмен контентом между приложениями реализован по типу клиент-сервер. Галерея - сервер, Ваше приложение - клиент, uri - адрес запроса ресурса. Только клиент и сервер физически располагаются на одной машине и клиент может получить прямой доступ к файлам сервера.  Но как бы Вы поступили на стороне клиента, не имея физического доступа к файлам сервера? Можно хранить ссылку, но думаю лучше сохранить копию картинки в папку приложения и потом брать её оттуда, ведь оригинал может быть удалён или перемещён другим приложением в любое время.

Comment: Логично. В моем случае это фото пользователя. Если он удалит свое старое фото, то захочет загрузить свое новое. Спасибо, запомню и это Ваше предложение. В PHP так и делается - создается папка в программе. Но PHP то обрабатывается весь сервером.

Comment: Да есть проблема с Uri. При повторной инсталляции APK приложение со ссылкой на Uri обваливается. Не подскажите ссылку как программно скопировать фото из галереи в папку наверное drawable?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо woess. Ваша идея сработала.

```
String imgUri = selectedImage.toString();
......
photoPath = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imgAddress"));
                ImageView newImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image);                   
                Uri newPath = Uri.parse(photoPath);
                newImage.setImageURI(newPath);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Корректно сработало только это:

```
public String convertToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,os);
    byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
}


public Bitmap convertToBitmap(String base64String) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmapResult = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    return bitmapResult;
}

....

        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_IMG, toBD);
        db.insert(TABLE_MYIMAGE, null, contentValues);
```